# Display Parent Calendar on sub site

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-calendar

Is there a way to display the calendar from the parent site on a sub site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in all my searching I was missing the key word, "Overlay". Got it. Thanks.

For the next person.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LfQFMOLbiO4